# Printing a dictionary in python with n elements per line

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, printing

Given a .txt with about 200,000 lines of single words, I need to count how many times each letter appears as the first letter of a word. I have a dictionary with keys 'a' - 'z', with counts assigned to each of their values. I need to print them out in the form

```
a:10,978 b:7,890 c:12,201 d:9,562 e:6,008
f:7,095 g:5,660 (...)
```

The dictionary currently prints like this

```
[('a', 10898), ('b', 9950), ('c', 17045), ('d', 10675), ('e', 7421), ('f', 7138), ('g', 5998), ('h', 6619), ('i', 7128), ('j', 1505), ('k'...
```

How do I remove the brackets & parentheses and print only 5 counts per line? Also, after I sorted the dictionary by keys, it started printing as key, value instead of key:value

```
def main():
    file_name = open('dictionary.txt', 'r').readlines()
    alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    letter = {}
    for i in alphabet:
        letter[i]=0
    for n in letter:
        for p in file_name:
            if p.startswith(n):
                letter[n] = letter[n]+1
    letter = sorted(letter.items())
    print(letter)
main()
```

Comment: You are reading the entire file for each letter.  You should make one pass through the file and just increment the correct count.

Comment: I would achieve that by putting the "for n in letter" loop inside the for "p in file_name" loop", correct?

Comment: a Counter dict will do what you want a lot more efficiently, your logic looks a bit suspect also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You couuld use the following:

It loops through your list, groups it by 5 elements, then prints it in the desired format.

In [15]:

```
letter = [('a', 10898), ('b', 9950), ('c', 17045), ('d', 10675), ('e', 7421), ('f', 7138), ('g', 5998), ('h', 6619), ('i', 7128), ('j', 1505)]
```

Replace `print(letter)` with following:

```
for grp in range(0, len(letter), 5):
    print(' '.join(elm[0] + ':' + '{:,}'.format(elm[1]) for elm in letter[grp:grp+5]))




a:10,898 b:9,950 c:17,045 d:10,675 e:7,421
f:7,138 g:5,998 h:6,619 i:7,128 j:1,505
```

Comment: This is the most direct answer to my question, thanks

Comment: @zachapp Note this will only print groups of 5.  You will have to modify it if you want to print a line with only 1 letter (for example 'z' counts)

Answer (score 0):

A collections.Counter dict will get the count of all the first letters on each line, then split into chunks and join:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('dictionary.txt') as f: # automatically closes your file
    # iterate once over the file object as opposed to storing 200k lines
    # and 26 iterations over the lines
    c = Counter(line[0] for line in f)
    srt = sorted(c.items())
    # create five element chunks from  the sorted items
    chunks = (srt[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(srt), 5))
    for chk in chunks:
        # format and join
        print(" ".join("{}:{:,}".format(c[0],c[1]) for c in chk))
```

If you may have something other than letters a-z use isalpha in the loop:

```
c = Counter(line[0] for line in f if line[0].isalpha())
```

There was a [Format Specifier for Thousands Separator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0378/) added in python 2.7.

Comment: Thank you this works. Could you explain what you mean by my logic looks a bit suspect? I am taking an intro to computer science course and I'm completely new to all this

Comment: Mostly `for p in file_name`, you are iterating over the list 26 times so `200000*26` as opposed to just doing a single pass. If you were going to go another way you would use `if p[0] in letter` and just do a single loop over the list of words and forget the loop over the dict. You code is very inefficient, storing all 200000 lines in memory at once along with 25 unnecessary iterations